$\bigwedge^2(\bigwedge^k\mathbb{C}^n)$ and $\operatorname{Sym}^2(\bigwedge^k\mathbb{C}^n)$ as $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$-modules
Consider the natural representations of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ in the spaces
$\bigwedge^2(\bigwedge^k\mathbb{C}^n)$ and $\operatorname{Sym}^2(\bigwedge^k\mathbb{C}^n)$.
Is it known how to decompose these representations into irreducible components?
I am particularly interested in the multiplicity of the irreducible representation with the highest weight $(2,\dots,2,0,\dots,0)$, where 2 is taken $k$ times, in these two spaces.

This is a problem about plethysm. Example 9 from Macdonald's book, in the section on plethysm, gives the formulas
$$ e_2 \circ e_k = \sum_{j \text{ odd}} s_{(k+j,k-j)'}$$
and
$$ h_2 \circ e_k = \sum_{j \text{ even}} s_{(k+j,k-j)'}.$$
The multiplicity you are asking about is the coefficient before $s_{(k,k)'}$. So the multiplicity is 1 in $\operatorname{Sym}^2 \bigwedge^k$ and $0$ in $\bigwedge^2 \bigwedge^k$.

Thank you. I did not understand your notation (I am not an expert in the field). What Macdonald’s book? Your last sentence relates to the representation $(2,…,2,0,…,0)$?

@asv I. G. Macdonald - Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials (1995, Oxford University Press, USA) page 140.
There is also a paper that deals with more general situation by Carré and Leclerc "Splitting the Square of a Schur Function into its Symmetric and Antisymmetric Parts". See e.g. http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/JACO/Volume4_3/v4251k50n37273n3.fulltext.pdf

@asv Yes. The prime denotes the transpose of a partition, so $(k,k)'=(2^k)$.
